# Pass value between methods through requests in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, httprequest, scrapy

I need to pass an array between two functions in Scrapy's Spider after make a new request (different from the actual). I will try to schematize to show it:

```
def newParse(self, response):
    array = []
    array.append(data1)
    array.append(data2)

def parse(self, response):
    ...................
    extract other data
    ...................
    yield scrapy.Request(newUrl, callback=self.newParse)

    # I want to recover my array here
```

Comment: If, `self` is an argument then I'm guessing this must be part of a class. It might be helpful if you demonstrate that.

Comment: you can pass information between requests, but shouldn't you be passing information from `parse` to `newParse` and not the other way around?